# Can't press CTRL + ALT + DEL

Tags: windows-7, ctrl-alt-delete

Good evening, I have 2 pc's here on which I cannot login.

Now when I power them on, I get to the log in screen but I cannot press ctrl + alt + del. I checked the keyboard but it works on my other pc.

Specs that I know:

(No videocards and it has RAM but the amount isn't on the RAM, and since I cannot log in I can't check it.

PC 1: Intel motherboard WIN7 Pro

PC 2: ASRock motherboard WIN7 Pro

Comment: Have you tried safe mode?

Comment: Did you plug the keyboard(s) into USB2 or USB3?

Comment: @Hennes you have almost 600 char available, can't you expand on that? like what difference(if any) it makes if it's plugged in usb2 vs in usb3. Or why you are asking that

Answer (score 0):

Is this a wired keyboard? If so, plug it into a different usb connector and boot up. Wait for a few minutes, maybe as long as 10, and see if it works. We have had computers that had new keyboards plugged in while they were off. When next booted, we couldn't login because the drivers had not loaded. Finally, they did load and login went on. A couple of times when it didn't work, we held in power button to kill power and rebooted. It did work then.